# What can cause (almost) all views on a SharePoint document library to lose all of their filter conditions?

Tags: 2007, infopath, view

My particular instance of this problem occured such that all but two of our document library views, and all connected web part pages lost their view filters. Detailed data points below.

- SharePoint 2007
- Document Library based on an InfoPath 2007 form
- Document library was in a subsite
- 10k+ Items
- 20 views
- ~50 web part pages using out of the box library view web parts referencing the views
- All views but two were affected

  - Thinking of it now, the two not affected, were not linked to web part pages.
- No other sites/sub sites/libraries seemed to have been affected by this 'hiccup'
- Filtering done on the webpart page via a query filter continued to operate as expected.

I would love to know what happened, or what could cause this in other instances.

Answer (score 0):

Did any fields change? Was there an update made to the form, maybe a field changed or removed. Sometimes InfoPath will add duplicate values. I would check your list settings to see if there are any duplicates of fields.

Comment: No fields were added or changed in the SharePoint library, and the InfoPath form was not republished/modified. The library itself had been stable for several months prior. We recovered from using a restore from backup, so unfortunately I can verify 100%, but I am reasonably sure that nothing had been changed directly with the library.